# Easy VSIX get started?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vs-extensibility, visual-studio-macros, visual-studio-extensions

I've created some macros in VS 2010, I now want to migrate them so they are VSIXs and publish them in the gallery.

They are built on top of the [`DTE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300825.aspx) object instance provided in the VS macro editor.

How to implement this?

What is the replacement for the [`DTE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300825.aspx) object?

**Update**
I also want to configure the extension so that when it's installed on the users machine, it should also install a keyboard shortcut that when pressed, it should run that method in the extension.
Note that currently I'm using a blank extension project, where there are no files except the code file that contains the method to be fired, and the *.vsixmanifest* file.
I've posted a separated question of the above: [How to make a shortcut to run a VSIX method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392622/how-to-make-a-shortcut-to-run-a-vsix-method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still reference DTE as a part of a VSIX extension. Just add a reference to the EnvDTE assembly. There's instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68shb4dw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on how to get the object. If you have an `IServiceProvider`, you can also `GetService(typeof(SDTE))` to get it.

Comment: +1. I managed to get to the `DTE`, please check my updated question.

Comment: Do you already have a menu item registered? How are you registering it? Also, what is this command? Is it some sort of text editor command or something else?

Comment: ...it might be better to start another question.

Comment: Here it is: [How to make a shortcut to run a VSIX method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392622/how-to-make-a-shortcut-to-run-a-vsix-method)