# How to make a shortcut to run a VSIX method?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsix, vs-extensibility, visual-studio-extensions

please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367439/easy-vsix-get-started/10367523) question.

The initial question was solved, and I have a method in my extension.
I want that when the user installs the extension, a keyboard-shortcut should be installed as well, and should run the method when pressed.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add shortcuts to the .vsct file.  This file is created automatically in the wizard when you generate a new extension and say it will have a menu command.  To add it manually:

- Create MyCommands.vsct
- Set File Properties to VSCTCompile
- Unload your project, right click and edit project:

```xml
<VSCTCompile Include="MyCommands.vsct">
    <ResourceName>Menus.ctmenu</ResourceName>
    <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</VSCTCompile>
```

- Declare that your project will have menus and shortcuts:

```cs
[ProvideMenuResource("Menus.ctmenu",1)]
public sealed class MyPackage : Package
```

- Add a keybindings section:

```xml
<KeyBindings>
   <KeyBinding guid="yourCmdSet" id="cmdAwesome"
    editor="guidVSStd97"
    key1="VK_F7" mod1="Control Alt"
    key2="VK_F1">
   </KeyBinding>
</KeyBindings>
```

- In your Package.Initialize:

```cs
// Add our command handlers for menu/shortcut (commands must exist in the .vsct file)
OleMenuCommandService mcs = GetService(typeof(IMenuCommandService)) as OleMenuCommandService;
if (null != mcs)
{
    //// Create the command for the menu item.
    var menuCommandID = new CommandID(GuidList.yourCmdSet,(int)PkgCmdIDList.cmdAwesome);
    var menuItem = new MenuCommand((sender, evt) =>
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

More resources:

- http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2008/04/17/LearnVSXNowPart18A.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb165138(v=vs.90).aspx
- http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2008/02/22/LearnVSXNowPart13.aspx

Comment: Also make sure the `<KeyBindings>` section is right after the `</Commands>`. I added it randomly in the file and got xml schema error.